# How to prevent direct access to a php page but can be accessed when redirected

Tags: php, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to prevent direct access to my error page which is `404.php` but I want that this page can be accessed when redirected from the other page.

Like my website name is `example.com/index.php` and if any user mistyped in any way like `example.com/ind.php` it will be redirected to my `404.php` to do that in my `.htaccess` file I have used.

Also, suppose in my `index.php` file I am showing some products when clicked on any product it is taking me to `product.php?pid=4` where `pid` contains the `id`, now I have put a condition that if `id!=4` or it does not exist then redirect it to `404.php`.

Everything up to this working very fine but if I access `example.com/404.php` it is showing me the page, I just want that the user when will direct use `example.com/404.php` it will redirect to `index.php` file. That's it.

```
# enable url rewriting
RewriteEngine On 
ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/news_21_off/404.php
```

Index.php

```
$sql = "select * from products";
$res = mysqli_query($co,$sql);
$rs = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res);

$res_id = $rs['id'];

<a href="products.php?pid=<?php echo $res_id; ?>">Product</a>
```

Products.php

```
if(isset($_GET['pid']) && $_GET['pid']=='4'){
echo 'correct';
}else{

header('location:404.php');
}
```

404.php

```
<h1>My 404 page</h1>
```

So far I have found no way of doing it.

Comment: Kindly do add your htaccess Rule file and samples/examples of urls(eg--> from which url to which url you want to redirect/rewrite?) for better understanding of your question, thank you.

Comment: Okay i am editing the question

Comment: This is not really possible by means of rewriting or the like. You'd need to implement a session management to track user navigation.

Comment: @arkascha please see again i have made the edit

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 please check i have made the edit

Comment: That rule you posted does not implement a redirection, that is an internal rewrite. So the question is what do you actually ask: prevent the access except after a _redirection_ , as you wrote in the question? Or prevent direct access, but allow it via that rewrite? Which would be trivial and only require to block direct access?

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to 302 "redirect" to the 404 page? This is not the usual way to serve a 404 response (you lose the details of the request that triggered the "error" and it won't serve a 404 HTTP response code, unless you manually set the HTTP status in your PHP).

Comment: @MrWhite no i just want to show the error file

Comment: Then fix that first, and use a relative URL for your ErrorDocument. And your PHP scripts should not _redirect_ there either - but rather issue a 404 status code themselves (if your 404.php) is not doing that already, and then _require_ that script, and exit after. In both cases, the REQUEST_URI in $_SERVER should still be what was originally requested, so you can check that that was _not_ the actual 404.php script to begin with - and respond with a 403 or whatever you think makes sense.

Comment: Although, that way you would rather be _exposing_ the existence of your 404.php - if you wanted to give users the impression, that URL did not exist … well then the response _should_ be 404.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Everything up to this working very fine...

Actually, I don't think it is...

> ...prevent direct access to a php page but can be accessed when redirected

This isn't just any PHP page. It is your 404 "Not Found" error document.

You should not be externally 3xx redirecting to your error document in the first place. The error document should be served in the *same request* (an "internal subrequest"). This is the root cause of your problem.

The redirected request is an entirely separate request, mostly indistinguishable from a "direct request", which will naturally make reliably blocking direct requests "impossible". However, do you really need to block "direct requests" to your 404 error document? (See below...)

> ```
> ErrorDocument 404 http://localhost/news_21_off/404.php
> ```

By specifying an absolute URL (ie. with a scheme + hostname) in the `ErrorDocument` directive, Apache will trigger a 302 external redirect to the stated URL. The user sees a 302 response (not a 404), followed by a 200 "OK" (not a 404) from the redirected request, unless you manually send the 404 "Not Found" status in your PHP code (there is no evidence of that here).

Just because Apache allows you to "redirect" to the error document, doesn't mean you should. As noted in the [Apache docs](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#errordocument):

> Note that when you specify an `ErrorDocument` that points to a remote URL (ie. anything with a method such as http in front of it), Apache HTTP Server will send a redirect to the client to tell it where to find the document, even if the document ends up being on the same server. **This has several implications, the most important being that the client will not receive the original error status code, but instead will receive a redirect status code. This in turn can confuse web robots and other clients which try to determine if a URL is valid using the status code.**

In addition, all the helpful PHP superglobals (passed from Apache) that ordinarily relate to the URL that triggered the 404 are lost (eg. `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_STATUS']`, `$_SERVER['REDIRECT_URL']`, etc.) because, as mentioned above, the redirected request is an entirely separate request.

99.99% of the time you should be using a root-relative URL-path in the `ErrorDocument` directive, so that Apache triggers an *internal subrequest* for the error document, for example:

```
ErrorDocument 404 /news_21_off/404.php
```

> ```
> header('location:404.php');
> ```

Likewise, you should not be "redirecting" to your error document in your PHP code either.

In PHP, there are various ways to resolve this. You could simply `include()` the error document at the point in your code you wish to serve the 404.

For example, in your `products.php` script:

```
<?php
$pid = $_GET['pid'] ?? null;
if ($pid == '4') {
    echo 'correct';
} else {
    // 404 Not Found
    include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/news_21_off/404.php');
    exit();
}
```

However, the above won't send a 404 HTTP status code to the client. In your PHP 404 error document you should set the HTTP status to ensure that a 404 status is sent by PHP and when/if the document is accessed directly by the user.

For example, in your `404.php` script:

```
<?php
http_response_code(404);
?>
<h1>My 404 page</h1>
```

Incidentally, setting the HTTP status code in your PHP script will override any status that Apache might have set when serving an error document.

Now, back to your initial question...

> I want to prevent direct access to my error page which is 404.php

Why?

Having implemented the changes above, if a user does "directly access" your 404 error document they are simply served a 404 and see the same response as if they had requested any other document that didn't exist.

So, unless you have a specific requirement, there is nothing more you need to do here.

Comment: Thanks I understood what do i need to do.